# Что означает $this в данном методе?

Tags: php

Есть такой метод:

```
function getInfo(){
   $arr = array();
   foreach($this as $k=>$v){
     $arr[$k] =$v;
   }
   return $arr;
}
```

Из теории я понимаю, что через `$this` мы обращаемся к свойству класса. Но обращение происходит так: `$this->свойство класса`. Здесь же нет второй части, а просто стоит `$this`, к чему мы получаем доступ через нее к `$arr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь происходит перебор всех свойств и их значений.

Код на [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/ShY6nr)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, понял.

Comment: ...или этот класс реализует интерфейс [`Iterator`][1]
...или этот класс наследует один из SPL классов для работы с объектом, как с массивом, в духе [`ArrayIterator`][2] или [`ArrayObject`][3]

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.iterator.php
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayiterator.php
  [3]: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayobject.php